# Passing a parameter to an XSL file with jcabi

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jcabi

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an XSL file with `jcabi-xml`. The code is simple and I can confirm that it executes:

```
final XSL xsl = new XSLDocument(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("test.xsl"));
xsl.with("test", "TestValue");
```

XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="test" select="''"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        ...
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$test"/></p>
        ...
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output is blank. Am I calling the wrong function? Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl.with` does not store the parameter in the same `xsl` variable but returns a new `XSL` object. So you need to write

```
xsl = xsl.with("test", "TestValue");
```

and then run the transformation.